# Unable to read from s3 bucket and write to same bucket a different file using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using the below Python3 shell code to read from S3 bucket, extract data and write to a new file in the same bucket. But the write operation is not working and Medicaid_Provider_ID_.txt is populated with zero rows. Any clue ??

```
import logging
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client("s3")

data = s3.get_object(Bucket='mmis.request.file', Key='MEIPASS_FISCAL_TRANS_ONE_RECORD.TXT')
file_lines = data['Body'].iter_lines()
next(file_lines)
new = []
id = 1

for line in file_lines:
    line_split = line.decode().split(',')
    MEDICAID_PROVIDER_ID = line_split[0]
    REASON_CODE = line_split[1]
    with open("Medicaid_Provider_ID_.txt","w") as f:
      f.writelines(MEDICAID_PROVIDER_ID)
      f.close()
id += 1
new = s3.put_object(Bucket='mmis.request.file', Key='Medicaid_Provider_ID_.txt')
```

Comment: Note: `writelines()` expects an iterable of strings. If you are writing a single string (the provider ID) then use `write()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code is recreating your file every single time the code runs:

```
with open("Medicaid_Provider_ID_.txt","w") as f:
```

You should open/create the file once, then iterate over all the rows in the file, then close the file when you are done. Like so:

```
import logging
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client("s3")

data = s3.get_object(Bucket='mmis.request.file', Key='MEIPASS_FISCAL_TRANS_ONE_RECORD.TXT')
file_lines = data['Body'].iter_lines()
next(file_lines)
new = []
id = 1

# Open the file
with open("Medicaid_Provider_ID_.txt","w") as f:
    # Write each line of the file
    for line in file_lines:
        line_split = line.decode().split(',')
        MEDICAID_PROVIDER_ID = line_split[0]
        REASON_CODE = line_split[1]
        f.writelines(MEDICAID_PROVIDER_ID)

    # Close the file
    f.close()
id += 1
new = s3.put_object(Bucket='mmis.request.file', Key='Medicaid_Provider_ID_.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. But the code is still writing zero rows to Medicaid_Provider_ID_.txt, not sure why :(

Comment: It would behoove you to do some debugging. You could completely eliminate AWS from the equation and start by writing this as a plain Python script that just reads a local file and writes a local file. Add some print lines or something to see if it is reading the values you think it is. Also fix the `writelines()` call as mentioned in the comments above.